# Filtering Events into Time Intervals

Tags: date, grouping, intervals

I'm trying to count how many events occur within 10 minutes period. How do I group a date like the following into 10 minutes intervals?

```
2017-10-16 14:08:43.0

2017-10-12 09:48:06.0

2017-10-16 09:01:54.0
```

Comment: You probably need a library/module which supplies utilities for manipulating dates and times. It depends on the programming language you use. Which programming language do you use?

Comment: impossible to answer unless we know the language is it SQL? (and is the database MySQL?) or is it for Java? the solution for SQL would be utterly different to the solution for Java. Please update your question with more detail. If you do need SQL also tell us which database you use.